# session management in android using sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, session-management

hi i successfully develped one login form with mysql database via soap webservices.here i wish to make session management.but i can't able to develop.so please help me.when i fill in the username and password is successful means it is go to next activity.the next activity have to displayed username.also if i click logout button means it is move to login form.now i ll go back means it is redirect to login page only...didnot go to displayed username activity.please guide me.

my code is:

```
package com.androidlogin.ws;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class AndroidLoginExampleActivity extends Activity {
 private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.userlogin.com";
 private final String URL = "http://111.223.128.10:8085/AndroidLogin/services/Login?wsdl";
 private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.userlogin.com/authentication";
 private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View arg0) {
loginAction();

}
});
}

private void loginAction(){
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
    String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
    String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

  //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

  //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordProp.setName("password");
    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

           TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
           result.setText(response.toString());
       if(status.equals("Success!"))
               {

                   //   ADD  to save  and  read next time
                       String strUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
                       String strPassword = userPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                       if (null == strUserName || strUserName.length() == 0)
                                   {
                           //  showToast("Enter Your Name");
                         userName.setError( "username is required!" );
isUserValidated = false;
                       }
 if (null == strPassword || strPassword.length() == 0)
                                   {
                               //      showToast("Enter Your Password");
 isPasswordValidated = false;
                         userPassword.setError( "password is required!" );
                       } 
 if(isUserValidated = true && isPasswordValidated == true)
                                   {

                           if (chkRememberMe.isChecked())
                                           {
                               SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                               loginPreferences.edit().putString(USERNAME, strUserName).putString(PASSWORD, strPassword).commit();
                           } else
                                           {
                               SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                               loginPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
                                           }
        }

        if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated)
     {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,HomePage.class);
                  **intent.putExtra("username",userName.getText().toString());**
                  startActivity(intent);
         }
      else
       {
     // what ever you want to do if the data in the EditText is not validated.
    //Maybe restart the same intent ?    
      // Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);    startActivity(i);


         }

                                   }

                       else
                          {
                           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                             startActivity(i);
                          }
                         }



    catch(Exception e){

    }
   }

  }
```

How is make session concepts using shared preferences in dis android login form application.

Thank You

Comment: when i fill in the username and password is successful means it is go to next activity.the next activity have to displayed username.also if i click logout button means it is move to login form.now i ll go back means it is redirect to login page only...didnot displayed username activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily implement this, if you use SharedPreferences and the Activities lifecycle.

Let's say you have `Activity A` - the display loging Activity, and `Activity B` - the logout Activity + display username Activity.

In `Activity A`, in your `loginAction()` method, put a boolean flag to track if the user is logged. If the user is valid, perform the login actions, set that flag to TRUE, than start your `Activity B`.

In `Activity B` in the `onResume()` method, make a check each time, if the flag is TRUE or FALSE. If the flag is TRUE do nothing, if the flag is FALSE start `Activity A` (back to login screen). Something like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    boolean isLogged = <yourSharedPrefs>.getBoolean(IS_LOGGED, Boolean.FALSE);

    if (!isLogged) {
                    //here start your login Activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityA.class));
    }

}
```

The logout button in `Activity B`, should set the flag to FALSE and than start `Activity A`.

This way when you click the back button, your app will load `Activity B`, but the check in `onResume()` will detect that the user is not logged, and `Activity A` will be started.

Comment: how is added above your sample code to my code.please explain detaily..where and how is added.

Comment: the above describes the idea and it is NOT all the code you need. Sorry but I don't have the time to integrate it with "your" code. If you can't figure how to use a boolean flag to control behavior, well...